# Use of Pseudo-Element ::before in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the CSS property `::before` in JavaScript?

My CSS code looks like this:

```css
#all-address::before
{
    content: '';
    height: 20px;       
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, white 45%, white   100%);
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
}
```

Now I want change `display: none` to `display: block` with help of JavaScript.

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("all-address");
div.pseudoStyle("before", "display", "block");
```

Comment: You do this by changing the classNames associated with the element. Is there a reason the pseudo would need to be controlled by JavaScript directly?

Comment: i was in the middle of writing the answer when this got closed. here.. https://jsfiddle.net/dpub1kjL/

Comment: Wanted to answer with CSS variable, solution added it to linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot access `:before` or `:after` from javascript, because they are not a part of the DOM. However you can still achieve your goal by using CSS classes. Example:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('abc').className += "minus";
</script>

<style>
    #all-address:before {
        display: none;
    }
    #all-address.minus:before {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks...
I add a + to script.
document.getElementById('abc').className += "minus";

Answer (score -3):

Try some think like this:

```
  window.getComputedStyle(
        document.querySelector('#all-address'), ':before'
    ).display='block';
```

Comment: Chrome gives `Uncaught NoModificationAllowedError: Failed to execute 'setProperty' on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the 'display' property is read-only` when using this.

Comment: Will throw error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setProperty' on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the 'display' property is read-only.`

Comment: Try new version. (property instead of method)